# Does N:N connection is possible via WiFi DIRECT on Ubuntu?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, wifi, wireless

I am searching for **wireless connection method** between robots using **WIFI DIRECT** in **Linux**.

I read many articles and papers, but I couldn't find any example of **1:N** and **N:N** connections in Linux(especially Ubuntu, ROS1) environment. I could only find information about Android.

Does anyone know ***if N:N connection is possible using WIFI DIRECT?***

If you know anything about this or have any other information on connecting multiple robots wireless, Plz reply.

Thanks.